# Algorithm problem into the brand slider in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want a brand slider without using a library or a package in angular. This works like that:

1 2 3(active) 4 5

2 3 4(active) 5 6

3 4 5(active) 6 7

4 5 6(active) 7 (empty)

5 6 7(active) (empty) (empty)

I want this in slider:

6 7 1(active) 2 3

7 1 2(active) 3 4

1 2 3(active) 4 5

2 3 4(active) 5 6

3 4 5(active) 6 7

4 5 6(active) 7 1

5 6 7(active) 1 2

This is the code in angular:

```
visibleLogos: Array<{ id: string; name: string; isActive: boolean, src: string }> = [];
private logoChangeInterval: Subscription;
```

...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.updateVisibleLogos();
}
```

...

```
    updateVisibleLogos() { //this is the problematic algorithm
    // Calculate start index
    const startIndex = this.activeLogoIndex % this.logos.length;
    console.log('startIndex: ' + startIndex);

    // Calculate end index
    let endIndex = (startIndex + 4) % this.logos.length;

    // Handle cases where endIndex is zero or smaller than startIndex
    if (endIndex === 0) {
        endIndex = this.logos.length - 1;
    } else if (endIndex < startIndex) {
        endIndex = endIndex + this.logos.length;
    }

    // Adjust endIndex if it exceeds the array length
    if (endIndex >= this.logos.length) {
        endIndex = this.logos.length - 1;
    }

    console.log('endIndex: ' + endIndex);

    // Dynamically slice the logos array based on adjusted indices
    this.visibleLogos = this.logos.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
    console.log(this.visibleLogos);

    // Set isActive property for visible logos
    for (const logo of this.visibleLogos) {
        logo.isActive = false;
    }

    // Set active logo to true for the middle logo
    this.visibleLogos[2].isActive = true;

    // Update the active index to the next position
    this.activeLogoIndex = (this.activeLogoIndex + 1) % this.logos.length;

    // Use setInterval to update logos at a consistent interval
    if (this.logoChangeInterval) {
        this.logoChangeInterval.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.logoChangeInterval = interval(3000).subscribe(() => this.updateVisibleLogos());
}
```

in html code:

```
  <div class="logo-slider">
       <ul class="w-full">
           <li class="bg-gradient" *ngFor="let logo of visibleLogos" [class.active]="logo.isActive"><img src="{{logo.src}}" alt="{{logo.name}}"></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

this is the scss code:

```
.logo-slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo-slider ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.logo-slider li {
    width: 20%; /* Adjust logo width to fit 5 logos per row */
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0.25;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo-slider li.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
updateVisibleLogos() {
    const startIndex = this.activeLogoIndex % this.logos.length;
    let endIndex = (startIndex + 4) % this.logos.length;
    if (endIndex === 0) {
        endIndex = this.logos.length - 1;
    } else if (endIndex < startIndex) {
        endIndex = endIndex + this.logos.length;
    }
    if (endIndex >= this.logos.length) {
        endIndex = this.logos.length - 1;
    }
    const visibleLogos = [];
    for (let i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        visibleLogos.push(this.logos[i]);
    }
    if (visibleLogos.length < 5) {
        const remainingLogos = this.logos.slice(0, 5 - visibleLogos.length);
        visibleLogos.push(...remainingLogos);
    }
    for (const logo of visibleLogos) {
        logo.isActive = false;
    }
    visibleLogos[2].isActive = true;
    this.activeLogoIndex = (this.activeLogoIndex + 1) % this.logos.length;
    this.visibleLogos = visibleLogos;
    if (this.logoChangeInterval) {
        this.logoChangeInterval.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.logoChangeInterval = interval(3000).subscribe(() => this.updateVisibleLogos());
}
```

Here is the answer.